# Emulator from Android Studio won't start

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

My environment: Windows 10, Android Studio 3.0 and latest SDK Tools at this time.

---

When trying to run the Android Emulator from Android Studio -> select my available AVD -> click OK and in Event Log I only get the following lines:

11/6/2017
5:42 PM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

**5:42 PM Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741511 (0xC0000139)**

5:42 PM Gradle build finished in 2s 611ms

Trying to run it from the command line:
G:\Android\sdk\emulator>.\emulator -avd NEXUS_5X_API_24

Gives me multiple errors refering to dll files:

- qemu-system-i386.exe - Entry Point Not Found
  The procedure entry point _Z4endlR11QTestStream could not be located in the dynamic link library: G:\Android\sdk\emulator\lib64\qt\lib\Qt5Svg.dll
- 3 more errors referring to dll in the same folder.

What I've tried so far:

- I've installed manually the dll files mentioned in the error pop-up, but it doesn't work.
- I've reinstalled Android Studio 2 times and nothing seems to work.
  The app goes fine on my device, but I can't check it on the Emulator.
- I tried with and without Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator installed

I searched for this error's solution, but can't make it work in any way.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I also put it as an issue on Android, I got an update on 25th March, but nothing else. It can be found here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68933522